# Update or insert a single ORM entry based on a unique (but not primary) key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, upsert

## env

- python 3.10
- SQLAlchemy: 1.4.44
- db: mysql 8

## description

I want to upsert a column instance extends Base.
I searched how to upseart, and find using insert(). https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#mysql-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

But I want to use Model extends Base. How to do it?

I want to use Base and Session(for commit, rollback).

```
mysql> desc foobar;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| company | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| memo    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import String

from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class Foobar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foobar'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    company = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    memo = Column(String(255), nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        columns = ', '.join([
            '{0}={1}'.format(k, repr(self.__dict__[k]))
            for k in self.__dict__.keys() if k[0] != '_'
        ])

        return '<{0}({1})>'.format(
            self.__class__.__name__, columns
        )


def main():
    session = None

    url = 'mysql+pymysql://scott:tiger@localhost:13306/df'
    engine = get_engine(url)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    # first insert
    insert_to_db(session, 'memo1')
    session.commit()

    # upsert insert
    insert_to_db(session, 'memo2')
    session.commit()


def get_engine(url):
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        url,
    )
    return engine


def insert_to_db(session, memo):
    foobar = Foobar(
        # email and company is uniq constraints.
        email='example@example.com',
        company='example',
        memo=memo,
    )

    print(f"============ {foobar}")

    ###########################
    # I want upsert here.
    ###########################
    session.add(foobar)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do the same thing as if you had a filing cabinet with (paper) documents in it. You would look for an existing document and if you found it you would update it. If you didn't find it you would create a new one and add it to the filing cabinet.

So for

```py
engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base = declarative_base()


class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "customer"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    memo = Column(String(255), nullable=True)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# load initial demo data
with Session(engine) as sess:
    sess.add(Customer(email="existing@example.com", memo="original value"))
    sess.commit()
```

your function would do exactly that

```py
def update_or_insert_customer(email, memo):
    with Session(engine) as update_sess:
        print(f"Looking for existing Customer with email {repr(email)}")
        cust = update_sess.scalars(
            select(Customer).where(Customer.email == email)
        ).first()
        if not cust:
            print(f"  existing Customer not found. Creating a new one.")
            update_sess.add(cust := Customer(email=email))
        else:
            print(f"  existing Customer found. Updating that one.")
        cust.memo = memo
        update_sess.commit()
```

and you would use it like this:

```py
update_or_insert_customer("new@example.com", "new entry")
"""
Looking for existing Customer with email 'new@example.com'
  existing Customer not found. Creating a new one.
"""
update_or_insert_customer("existing@example.com", "updated value")
"""
Looking for existing Customer with email 'existing@example.com'
  existing Customer found. Updating that one.
"""

# check the table
print(f'Table "{Customer.__tablename__}" contains:')
with engine.begin() as conn:
    print(conn.execute(select(Customer.__table__)).all())
"""
Table "customer" contains:
[(1, 'existing@example.com', 'updated value'), (2, 'new@example.com', 'new entry')]
"""
```

Comment: This is not upsert. it is select and insert or update.
upsert is 1 operetion and select and insert or update need 2 operation, so it takes twice as long.
I want do upsert.